# HTML Web Resource unable to display all lines

Tags: html, dynamics-crm, webresource

I have a `HTML` web resource in Dynamics 365 which displays a list of text. However, the output is unable to display all lines, resulting in the last 2 lines being cut off. May I know how can I solve it?

---

[image]

---

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    <font face="Arial"><b><u>Test List</u></b></font>
    <ol class="RTE_list_style_position">
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 1</font></li>
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 2</font></li>
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 3</font></li>
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 4</font></li>
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 5</font></li>
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 6</font></li>
        <li><font face="Arial">Test line 7</font></li>
    </ol>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height by setting this “Number of Rows” in form editor webresource properties. Also you can check that “Automatically expand to use available space” checkbox.

[image]

[Read more](https://dynamicsninja.blog/2018/07/21/change-webresource-height-dinamicaly/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arun. I have tried this method but weirdly enough it didn't work. I have no idea. I resulted in using javascript to modify the height of the iframe. However, this method should work.

Comment: Yes I did, according to your method. But I used javascript at the end.

Comment: @gymcode it should work, maybe uncheck & row increase needed. Btw the js script is unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try changing the overflow to this:

`<body onfocusout="parent.setEmailRange();" style="overflow: auto;">`